# UIKit live preview, like swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

what UIKit have a live preview in xcode? like swiftUI have a live priview on xcode. when you writing code with swiftUI, you can show result design in left xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code by importing SwiftUI. You can create new file or put it below your ViewController code.

```
struct MainViewController_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {
        return ContentView()
    }
    
    struct ContentView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MainViewController {
            return MainViewController()
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MainViewController, context: Context) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to IgnoringSafeArea, just add ContentView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) and for specific device type you can use .previewDevice(.init(stringLiteral: "DEVICE_TYPE")) // iPhone 11 Pro

Comment: have i need to import swiftUI?

Comment: Replace MainViewController with your ViewController name.

Yes, you need to import SwiftUI first, because PreviewProvider protocol it's not available in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

To make your ViewControllers work with Xcode previews

1 - Make them representable by conforming **UIViewControllerRepesentable** protocol.

```
struct YourVCRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        // leave this empty
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        YourViewController() // this is to make your view controller representable
    }
}
```

2 - Create Preview provider struct that conforms to **PreviewProvider** protocol and pass the above created RepresentableViewController.

```
struct YourVCPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       YourVCRepresentable()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Xcode 15** we can create previews with new syntax using the ***#Preview*** macro.

```
#Preview {
     MyViewController()
}

#Preview {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("UIButton", for: .normal)
    
    return button
}
```

Xcode 14:

a. Create extension

```
import SwiftUI

extension UIViewController {
    
    private struct Preview: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        let viewController: UIViewController
        
        func makeUIViewController (context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
            viewController
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
            
        }
    }
    
    func showPreview() -> some View {
        Preview(viewController: self).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

b. Add to your *MyViewController* class

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewControllerProvider: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyViewController().showPreview()
    }
}
```